# How to handle Oracle bulk inserts with transactions if a transaction state unknown error is recived

Tags: oracle, transactions, oracle-call-interface

In my application I have used Oracle (OCI) bulk executions using the following function.

```
OCIStmtExecute
```

For all the normal conditions it works as expected. Once Oracle node failover happened it gives rejections like "ORA-25405" in commits.

```
ORA-25405: transaction status unknown
```

According to the guide lines available all says "The user must determine the transaction's status manually".

My Question is will there be a scenario where my bulk insert/update works partially giving the above error?

Comment: Hi Sujith, it is not clear whether you want to avoid the exception or if you want to catch it and do a workaround. There seem to be a contradiction between your title and the *will there be a scenario* at the end...

Comment: Actually I need to catch the error and do a workaround. Because even if the TAF is configured correctly, the same error are even possible.

Comment: And you would like to know if rows have been inserted even though there was an error at commit time? I advise you to edit your question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci16m89.htm

> With global transactions, it is possible that the transaction is now in-doubt, meaning that it is neither committed nor aborted.

This is exactly your case. This means the transaction isn't committed.

> `OCITransCommit()` attempts to retrieve the status of the transaction from the server. The status is returned.

The solution then is to try again to commit the transaction with `OCITransCommit()`, then get the return value and check it.